SwiftUI and Realm - Abrupt back navigation when modifying a collection on a realm object in nested views
I store two types of Objects in the Realm:

Items
SubItems

Items can have a collection of SubItems.
final class Item: Object, ObjectKeyIdentifiable {
    @Persisted(primaryKey: true) var id: ObjectId
    @Persisted var name: String
    @Persisted var subItems = RealmSwift.List<SubItem>()
}

final class SubItem: Object, ObjectKeyIdentifiable {
    @Persisted(primaryKey: true) var id: ObjectId
    @Persisted var name: String
}

I have three views in a SwiftUI app:

a list of Items
a detailed view of a single Item
a SubItem picker which lets the user add or remove SubItems to the selected Item

When the user is on the SubItemPicker, and they add or remove a SubItem (i.e. change in the selected item), the navigation abruptly goes back to the previous view (i.e. DetailView).
I would have expected the user to remain on the SubItemPickerView.
The List view
struct ContentView: View {
    @ObservedResults(Item.self) var items
    @ObservedResults(SubItem.self) var subItems
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            VStack {
                List(items) { item in
                    NavigationLink(destination: DetailView(item: item)) {
                        Text(item.name)
                    }
                }
                Button("Add Item") {
                    let newItem = Item()
                    newItem.name = "New Item \(Date())"  // Example name based on the current date and time
                    
                    let realm = try! Realm()
                    try! realm.write {
                        realm.add(newItem)
                    }
                }
            }
            .navigationBarTitle("Items")
        }
        .onAppear {
            if subItems.isEmpty {
                let names = ["Cedric Mckinney", "Daniel Fleming", "Noel Hopkins", "Caitlyn Tucker", "Mariana Glover"]
                for name in names {
                    let subItem = SubItem()
                    subItem.name = name
                    $subItems.append(subItem)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

The DetailView
struct DetailView: View {
    @ObservedRealmObject var item: Item
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text(item.name)
                .font(.largeTitle)
                List(item.subItems) { subItem in
                Text(subItem.name)
            }
            NavigationLink(destination: SubItemPicker(selectedItem: item)) {
                Text("Select Contact")
            }
        }
    }
}

The SubItemPicker
struct SubItemPicker: View {
    @ObservedResults(SubItem.self) var subItems
    @ObservedRealmObject var selectedItem: Item

    var body: some View {
        List(subItems) { subItem in
            Button(action: {
                if let index = selectedItem.subItems.firstIndex(where: { $0.id == subItem.id }) {
                     $selectedItem.subItems.remove(at: index)
                } else {
                    $selectedItem.subItems.append(subItem)
                }
            }) {
                HStack {
                    Text(subItem.name)
                    Spacer()
                    if selectedItem.subItems.contains(where: { $0.id == subItem.id }) {
                        Image(systemName: "checkmark.circle.fill")
                    } else {
                        Image(systemName: "circle")
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

I tried not using the $ notation.
I also implemented a workaround where the selected SubItems are temporarily stored in an Array and modified then. However, when saving back to the Item object the abrupt navigation back occurs again, so it's just a workaround.
